# Filter out rows that contain duplicate numbers

Tags: matlab

The second row in the following matrix contains two 3's. All the other rows don't contain duplicates.

```
A = [1 2 3; 
     1 3 3;  
     4 5 6]
```

What's an efficient way to filter out rows containing duplicates such that the result is the following?

```
A = [1 2 3;
     4 5 6]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is reasonably fast:

```
A( all(diff(sort(A,2),[],2), 2), :);
```

If `A` is `M×N`, then the complexity of this is `O(M·N·log(N))`...I have a hunch this is the fastest way possible, but I'm unable to prove this. Anyone?

Comment: I think you are right.  The `sort`/`diff` method is pretty fast.